# XML validation error: No document Element?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I don't understand why this DTD from an XML document will not validate. The error it's giving me is "no document element" on the last line. Which is stupid because I can delete all but two lines of this code and it still gives me the error. I'm fairly beginner at XML so maybe someone with a little more experience take a look for me?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE events [
<!ELEMENT events (event)+>
<!ELEMENT event (itenerary, description, icon?, leader+, coordinator+, maxpart, registeredpart, carpool?, difficulty, cost?, destination)>
<!ELEMENT itenerary (startdate, enddate, departuretime, location)>
<!ELEMENT contact (name,phone+)>
<!ELEMENT name (firstname, lastname)>
<!ELEMENT startdate (year, month, day)>
<!ELEMENT enddate (year, month, day)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT departuretime (hours,minutes)>
<!ELEMENT hours (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT minutes (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT location (street,city)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT icon (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT leader (contact+)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (landline?, cell?)> 
<!ELEMENT coordinator (contact)>
<!ELEMENT landline (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cell (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT maxpart (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT registeredpart (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT carpool (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT difficulty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cost (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT destination (location)> 
]>
```

Comment: Can you post the precise error message as well as a [short example document](http://sscce.org/#short) that triggers the error?

Comment: error is happening on the last line at `]>` and it's currently not being used by any documents. Its currently just a free standing dtd in xml format.

Comment: Ok, but what tool are you using then to validate the DTD, and what is the *precise output* you get?

Comment: Im using WC3 validation services. The error is number 100: "Line 5, Column 3: no document element
]>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [W3C XML/HTML Markup Validation](http://validator.w3.org/) service just validates documents, and not DTDs themselves. Append a valid document to your DTD to check both DTD and document, [like this](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fphihag.de%2F2013%2Fso%2Fdtd-14550812.xml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE events [
<!ELEMENT events (event)+>
<!ELEMENT event (itenerary, description, icon?, leader+, coordinator+, maxpart, registeredpart, carpool?, difficulty, cost?, destination)>
<!ELEMENT itenerary (startdate, enddate, departuretime, location)>
<!ELEMENT contact (name,phone+)>
<!ELEMENT name (firstname, lastname)>
<!ELEMENT startdate (year, month, day)>
<!ELEMENT enddate (year, month, day)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT month (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT day (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT departuretime (hours,minutes)>
<!ELEMENT hours (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT minutes (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT location (street,city)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT icon (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT leader (contact+)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (landline?, cell?)> 
<!ELEMENT coordinator (contact)>
<!ELEMENT landline (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cell (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT maxpart (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT registeredpart (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT carpool (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT difficulty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cost (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT destination (location)> 
]>
<events>
  <event>
    <itenerary><!-- Did you mean itinerary ? -->
      <startdate><year>2013</year><month>1</month><day>1</day></startdate>
      <enddate><year>2013</year><month>1</month><day>2</day></enddate>
      <departuretime><hours>12</hours><minutes>01</minutes></departuretime>
      <location>
        <street>Kölner Straße</street>
        <city>Düsseldorf</city>
      </location>
    </itenerary>
    <description>A short trip</description>
    <leader>
      <contact><name><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></name><phone/></contact>
    </leader>
    <coordinator>
      <contact><name><firstname>Jane</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></name><phone/></contact>
    </coordinator>
    <maxpart>??</maxpart>
    <registeredpart>???</registeredpart>
    <difficulty>easy</difficulty>
    <destination>
      <location>
        <street>Aachener Straße</street>
        <city>Düsseldorf</city>
      </location>
    </destination>
  </event>
</events>
```

Comment: Ah, its because I need some substance to go with the dtd, and the no Document element is because I literally have no document in the xml. Correct?

Comment: @GivenPie Yup, precisely. Added an example (with link) which validates.